# Jakarta JSON excludes null fields even though withNullValues is set to true

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee, java-ee-8

I have this code that runs on Tomee with Jakarta EE 9.1, it is supposed to generate a JSON string taking the data from `inputObj`. Problem is that there are fields with null values that are omitted from the resulting JSON even though `withNullValues` is set to true. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```java
JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withNullValues(true);
                    
String json;
try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config)) {
    json = jsonb.toJson(inputObj);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr; solved.

---

After I had read from your following comment, I solved your issue.

> No, the only annotation is at the field name level
> @JsonbProperty("field_name"), and nothing at the class level.

The annotation's default `nillable` value is `false` . To accomplish your request you need to make it `true` as following.

```
@JsonbProperty(value = "test", nillable = true)
public String your_field_name;
```

It yields something like `{... your other json fields, "test":null}`

---

To begin, I have never used before this post JSON-B API. For you, I have installed it and its dependencies via [its official webpage](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/getting-started.html).

I have started a simple console app and created `pom.xml` to leverage its Maven dependencies as written on the webpage.

*I think your problem is as to the versions either that of its dependencies or directly its own version.*

**Don't forget to *reload project* after changing any settings related to Maven.**

What my `pom.xml` includes is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>RefUrself</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

     <!-- ** The rest is for JSON-B API ** -->

    <repositories>
        <!-- Needed for JSON-B API -->
        <repository>
            <id>java.net-Public</id>
            <name>Maven Java Net Snapshots and Releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

And, when I run its official example which is `Dog` class in which I changed name of the dog to `null`, it works like a charm.

`Dog` class

```
public class Dog {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public boolean bitable;
}
```

The `Test` class in which the program begins to run

```
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbConfig;

public class Test {
    // Create a dog instance
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.name = null; // --> null as you see
        dog.age = 4;
        dog.bitable = false;

        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withNullValues(true);
        // Create Jsonb and serialize
        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config)) {
            String result = jsonb.toJson(dog);
            System.out.println(result);
            //{"age":4,"bitable":false,"name":null}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible there are annotations on the fields of `inputObj` you are serializing that are overriding the `.withNullValues(true)` setting?

Ref: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonb/3.0/jakarta-jsonb-spec-3.0.html#customizing-null-handling

I also found this: https://github.com/jakartaee/jsonb-api/issues/169#issuecomment-525387593

You didn't share the class for `inputObj` but it seems to me like the only way this won't work is if there are annotations on the fields in the class overriding the global setting in `config`.

Comment: No, the only annotation is at the field name level `@JsonbProperty("field_name")`, and nothing at the class level.

Comment: So @JsonProperty is the issue after all, just like I said :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your full code, so this is my guess. If you don't declare `getter` method for properties in class, `Json-B` skips to serialize fields. Here is my example.

##### Without Getter

```java
package action.in.blog;

import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class JsonbTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withNullValues(true);

        Input inputObj = new Input();

        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config)) {
            System.out.println(jsonb.toJson(inputObj));
        }
    }

    public static class Input {
        private String value;
    }
}
```

##### Result when without getter

```
{}
```

##### With Getter

```java
package action.in.blog;

import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class JsonbTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withNullValues(true);

        Input inputObj = new Input();

        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config)) {
            System.out.println(jsonb.toJson(inputObj));
        }
    }

    public static class Input {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

##### Result when with getter

```
{"value":null}
```

##### With public keyword

If you don't use getter method for fields, fields should be public.

```java
package action.in.blog;

import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class JsonbTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withNullValues(true);

        Input inputObj = new Input();

        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config)) {
            System.out.println(jsonb.toJson(inputObj));
        }
    }

    public static class Input {
        public String value;
    }
}
```

##### Result when with public

```
{"value":null}
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have getter and setter, still the field is not in the resulting json when the value is null

Comment: Can you show us more details? How does Input class implement and what are values set up in object?

Comment: it has nothing to do with getter etc. at all.